# Api type [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource] is not found with the qualifiers

Tags: java, dependency-injection, websocket, atmosphere, tomee-7

I'm doing a websocket app using Atmosphere and I'm trying to reproduce the [chat sample](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/master/samples/chat) in my own environment. I'm working with a TomEE 7 plus server, and the sample works fine on it.

I added the maven dependency to atmosphere-runtime and to servlet 3.0 as is it done in the sample

```
    <!-- PubSub dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spécification servlet 3.0 nécessaire pour atmosphere -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I put my servlet in the web.xml file

```
<!-- Atmosphere Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- limit classpath scanning to speed up starting, not mandatory -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.web.websocket</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor.clientHeartbeatFrequencyInSeconds</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/chat/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But then when I try to Inject `AtmosphereResource` in my `Chat` class I got this error :

```
 GRAVE: CDI Beans module deployment failed
org.apache.webbeans.exception.inject.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  resource, Bean Owner : [Chat, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API Types:[my.package.web.websocket.Chat,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:215)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:846)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:652)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1261)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  resource, Bean Owner : [Chat, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API Types:[my.package.wen.websocket.Chat,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtil.throwUnsatisfiedResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtil.java:60)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectionResolver.checkInjectionPoint(InjectionResolver.java:195)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.validate(BeanManagerImpl.java:960)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validate(BeansDeployer.java:491)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints(BeansDeployer.java:422)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:202)
    ... 18 more
```

Ha and another usefull Information I don't use the `ObjectMapperInjectable.java` so I don't have the `META-INF/Services/org.atmosphere.inject.Injectable` file (it's used in the sample).
And I have a beans.xml in my projet, i'm able to inject my business service in `Chat.java`

I understand that it doesn't find the Default qualifier, but I don't understand why.

Do I need to specify a Qualifier for AtmospherResource interface (I don't think so) ? Are not there a default implementation ?

Is there someone who solved the same problem ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

After some test it seems come from the beans.xml. If I add it in the original sample project under META-INF/ I got the same error.